# How to remove the Require form JQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, dreamweaver

I have a form that uses a JQuery Validation plugin. It is working correctly, however the problem is that all fields are required and I would like to remove the "require" validation for some fields. 
Here is my javaScript

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.validate({


  modules : 'sweden',
  onModulesLoaded : function() {
    $('input[name="Lan"]').suggestSwedishCounty();
    $('input[name="Ort"]').suggestSwedishMunicipality();

  }

});
</script>
```

I am aware that I can change the "rules" and even custom the error message, but how would it look like and more importantly: Where would I put it?
Here is my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction ?>" id="minForm">
<INPUT TYPE=button VALUE="Tillbaka till patienter" onclick=window.history.back()>
 <h3>Skapa person</h3>
  <p>
    <strong>Personnummer:</strong> <br />
    <input name="Personnummer" id="Personnummer" data-validation="swesec" data-validation-use-hyphen="true">
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Namn:</strong> <br />
    <input name="Namn" id="Namn" data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-allowing="åäö">
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Efternamn:</strong> <br />
    <input name="Efternamn" id="Efternamn" data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-allowing="åäö">
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Kön:</strong><br />
    <select name="kon">
    <option value="NULL">Välj</option>
      <option value="Man">Man</option>
      <option value="Kvinna">Kvinna</option>
    </select>
  </p>
   <strong> Län</strong> <br />
    <input name="Lan" id="Län" data-validation="swecounty"> 
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Ort</strong> <br />
    <input name="Ort" id="Ort" data-validation="swemunicipality" >
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit">
  </p>
   <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2"/>
</form>
```

Thank you...

Comment: From which fields should they be removed?

Comment: All except the first one (Personnummer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just as simple as removing the `data-validation` tags in the elements, that's what works in my code, i use it too.

Comment: yes, but I want to keep the validation, I just want to make it non-required. Right now everything is required.

Answer (score 0):

So when there is something is should be correct? If that is the case, i dont know how to do that. You might ask yourself what the function is.

Comment: For example, the fields **Lan** and **Ort** checks that the input city is correct (here in Sweden). But I don't want the field to be required (I want it to allow NULL)